# row editing is not working in datatable primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

During editing of datatable values, the values are not updated in the screen as well as in listener method. The listener method:

```
public void onEdit(RowEditEvent event) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
{
    Employee e=(Employee) event.getObject();
    name=e.getName();
    department=e.getDepartment();
    salary=e.getSalary();
    place=e.getPlace();
          ......
           ..... update query
}
```

I get only the selected object and its values, but not the updated values.

This is my datatable XHTML:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />

    <p:dataTable var="e" value="#{employees.eList}" id="elist1"
        editable="true">
        <f:facet name="header">
        In-Cell Editing
    </f:facet>

        <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{employees.onEdit}"
            update=":form:messages" />
        <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{employees.onCancel}"
            update=":form:messages" />

        <p:column headerText="name" style="width:30%">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{e.name}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <h:inputText value="#{e.name}" style="width:100%" />
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="department" style="width:20%">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{e.department}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <h:inputText value="#{e.department}" style="width:100%"
                        label="department" />
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="salary" style="width:20%">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{e.salary}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <h:inputText value="#{e.salary}" style="width:100%" label="salary" />
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="place" style="width:20%">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{e.place}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <h:inputText value="#{e.place}" style="width:100%" label="place" />
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>



        <p:column style="width:6%">
            <p:rowEditor />
        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>

</h:form>
```

This is my managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "employees")
@ViewScoped
public class UserData  
{
    // properties
    private String name;
    private String department;
    private String salary;
    private String place;
    private ArrayList<Employee> eList;
    private Employee selectedemp;



    private void clear()
    {
        name="";
        department="";
        salary="";
        place="";
    }

//returning all employees   
    public ArrayList<Employee> geteList() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Connection conn=DbConnection.connectFunc();
        Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
        String sql="select * from employee";
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        eList=new ArrayList<Employee>();
        while(rs.next())
        {
            Employee emp=new Employee();
            emp.setName(rs.getString(2));
            emp.setDepartment(rs.getString(3));
            emp.setSalary(rs.getString(4));
            emp.setPlace(rs.getString(5));
            eList.add(emp);
        }
        return eList;
    }
public void onEdit(RowEditEvent event) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {

    Employee e=(Employee) event.getObject();
     name=e.getName();
        System.out.println(name);
        department=e.getDepartment();
        System.out.println(department);
        salary=e.getSalary();
        System.out.println(salary);
        place=e.getPlace();
        System.out.println(place);

        Connection conn=DbConnection.connectFunc();
        Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
        String sql="update employee set department='"+department+"',salary='"+salary+"',place='"+place+"'where name='"+name+"'";
        int i=stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        if(i!=0)
        {
            FacesContext context=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("updated  successfully"));
        }
        conn.close();
    }
//onCancel
    public void onCancel(RowEditEvent event)
    {

    }
...setter and getters
```

If i use view scope, the following exception occurs:

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.io.NotSerializableException: com.solv.datatable.UserData
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    java.util.HashMap.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(Unknown Source)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    java.util.HashMap.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.ClientSideStateHelper.doWriteState(ClientSideStateHelper.java:325)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.ClientSideStateHelper.writeState(ClientSideStateHelper.java:173)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.ResponseStateManagerImpl.writeState(ResponseStateManagerImpl.java:122)
    com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.writeState(StateManagerImpl.java:166)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.WriteBehindStateWriter.flushToWriter(WriteBehindStateWriter.java:225)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:419)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:410)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.26 logs.
```

Comment: what scope you using? maybe you can give some datatable code?

Comment: @Darka hi i added the datatable code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your bean must implement interface Serializable. That's what the error message says

The other problem is that you always return new List by getEList. You can load your ArayList in some kind of init method that will have annotation `@PostConstruct`.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
       //code from getElist()...
}
```

And your getter shuld be classic getter that only returns eList.
 In that way you load your list when your view is created. In your case every update will load list again that is bad practice. Do not fetch data in getter. Editting is not working for you because you lose updated values by returning a new list every time.

Comment: well exception rectified...but i don't get updated values, still getting the old values

Comment: Ok, again: Does execution enters method onEdit at all? Have you checked this?

Comment: yes it enters onEdit method, what i am saying is,  event.getObject() method  returns old object not updated one

Comment: I'va updated my answer. I haven't noticed  at first that the problem was your  geteList().

Comment: Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problems.

Comment: I need 15 reputation to vote up the answer. but i have only 8

Answer (score 1):

In your

```
<p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{employees.onEdit}"
            update=":form:messages" />
```

you only update messagess and not datatable itself. Try this:  `update=":form:messages, :form:elist1"`.
That works for me

Comment: I changed code as <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{employees.onEdit}"
update=":form:messages,:form:elist1" />  <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{employees.onCancel}"
update=":form:messages,:form:elist1" /> but no change

Comment: What scope you use? Is it view scoped bean? Have you done debugging? Do you enter this method or not?

Comment: i am using request scope. i updated the datatable component, with your code,  but still it is not working..

Comment: Why do you use request scope instead of view scope? Do you have specific reason? This update that I suggested have no meaning in request scope.

Comment: I changed the scope to view..but exception is there. i paste the exception and my managed bean in my question

Comment: What exception do you get? And did you check in debug mode if execution enters method onEdit?

Comment: if i use view scope exception occurs , i updated the exception in my question..http status 500

Answer (score 0):

I think you either:

- Need to define the rowKey attribute on the p:dataTable tag.
- Or implement a datamodel (that you feed into the datatable) that implements SelectableDataModel.

The rowKey attribute option would require the least amount of work. e.g:
`<p:dataTable var="e" value="#{employees.eList}" id="elist1" rowKey="#{e.name}"
        editable="true">`

where e.name is the identifier for each item in the datatable. It also should be a unique value for that object. (like an id)

Comment: I don't get why he (or anyone else) shouldn't use view scoped bean?

Comment: Yeah you're right, on second thought viewscoped should be fine (removed that from my answer)

Answer (score 0):

It might help somebody. I had a similar issue and I tried every possible thing on the internet. Eventually I gave up, but accidentally fixed it later. The issue was that I had multiple < h:form> used in my .xhtml and the changes were not propagated for some reason. 
Hope it helps somebody.